# How would we evaluate the definite integral $ \int_0^{e^{\frac{1}{e}}}\frac {-W(-\ln(x))}{\ln(x)}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, lambert-w

How would we evaluate the definite integral: 
$$ \int_0^{e^{\frac{1}{e}}}\frac {-W(-\ln(x))}{\ln(x)}dx $$

Here $W$ is the Lambert W function. More information about this function can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Edit 1: Found a mistake in the limits so corrected it.

Edit 2: Here are some alternate forms that I derived that might help:

$$ \int_{-1/e}^{\infty} e^{(-u-W(u))}du $$
$$ -\int_{-1/e}^{\infty} \frac{W(x)}{Inv(W(x))}du $$
$$ \int_{-1/e}^{\infty} \frac { \sum_{n=0}^{ \infty } \frac {(-1)^{n-1}n^{n-1}x^{n}} {n!}} {x\sum_{n=0}^{ \infty }\frac{x^n}{n!} } dx$$

Edit 3: After a bit of more investigation, I have managed to further simplify the integral:
$$ \int_0^{e^{\frac{1}{e}}}\frac {-W(-\ln(x))}{\ln(x)}dx = -\int_{-1/e}^{\infty} \frac{W(u)}{u(e^u)}du = -\int_{-1/e}^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^nT(n)u^n }{n!}du = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[ \frac {(-1)^nT(n)u^{(n+1)} }{n!(n+1)} \right]_{-1/e}^{\infty} $$

where 
T(n)
counts the number of forests of rooted labeled trees using labels in a subset of 
{1,⋯,n}
, which is also the hyperbinomial transform of the constant sequence of 
1's. (See [A088957](https://oeis.org/A088957).)

Now the problem is that I don't know how to evaluate this summation due to T(n), and even wolfram alpha cant do it. Any help on evaluating this summation?

Comment: The proper spelling is definite, not definate. I fixed it for you.

Comment: ahh a typo thank you

Comment: Since the function $W$ can't be expressed in terms of elementary functions, you could try evaluating the integral numerically.

Comment: An equivalent expression is $$\int_{-\frac1{e}}^\infty\exp(-u-W(u))\mathrm du$$ which is effectively a Laplace transform plus a dangling constant.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician Yes I just derived that but have no idea how to proceed forward.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician will expanding it to $ \frac { \sum_{n=0}^{ \infty } \frac {(-1)^{n-1}n^{n-1}x^{n}} {n!}} {x\sum_{n=0}^{ \infty }\frac{x^n}{n!} }$ help?

Comment: Are you sure the lower limit of integration is zero? If it was $1/e^e$ then the integrand would correspond to Euler's infinite iterated exponential function of $$h(x) = x^{x^{x^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot}}}}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

*Not an answer but approximation.*

If we consider the function $$f(x)=-\frac {W(-\ln(x))}{\ln(x)}$$ we can notice that $xf(x)$ looks like a power law.

Then, I thought that we could get some reasonable approximations writing
$$xf(x)=\sum_{n=1}^p a_n x^{bn}$$ Using $p=4$, the results from a quick and dirty regression leads to
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a_1 & +0.49967 & 0.00119 & \{+0.49731,+0.50203\} \\
 a_2 & +0.58096 & 0.00575 & \{+0.56954,+0.59239\} \\
 a_3 & +1.27106 & 0.04029 & \{+1.19105,+1.35106\} \\
 a_4 & -0.72606 & 0.02198 & \{-0.76971,-0.68242\} \\
 b   & +1.13077 & 0.00065 & \{+1.12948,+1.13206\} 
\end{array}$$
 and computing
$$I(t)=-\int_0^t \frac {W(-\ln(x))}{\ln(x)}\,dx$$ we should have the following results (not fantastic, I agree !)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 t & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 0.05 & 0.015218 & 0.015313 \\
 0.10 & 0.034027 & 0.034118 \\
 0.15 & 0.054945 & 0.055038 \\
 0.20 & 0.077617 & 0.077711 \\
 0.25 & 0.101866 & 0.101959 \\
 0.30 & 0.127595 & 0.127687 \\
 0.35 & 0.154749 & 0.154842
\end{array}
\right)$$

For sure, this could be made better at the price of more parameters using for example
$$xf(x)=\sum_{n=1}^p a_n x^{b_n}$$

Comment: Thanks for this man. This could help. Also I recently edited the question in which I found the indefinite integral in summation form. Do you have any idea on how to evaluate this summation?

Comment: @RithikKapoor. No idea at all !

Comment: Also I am not familiar with the T(n) function and only used it as I found this relation in a math paper. Do you know whether it is the same as tree(n) function. If so then wouldn't it produce extremely big numbers when n>2?

Answer (score 0):

**Not an answer**

Change variables $y=-W(-\log x)$ to convert it to the integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{1}(1-y)\exp(ye^{-y})\;dy
$$
But that is still not elementary of course.